# Just Keep Adding!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Start with me and I come last,
>
> Add one and I become excited,
>
> Add another and I call someone,
>
> Keep going and you will get something trendy,
>
> Add another and you will want me,
>
> Well now, add another and I will look like a weird balance,
>
> Add another and I'll bring you up,
>
> Yes, yes keep going and, and, and...?
>
> Well okay add another, and there will always be more.
>
> Add the last and final, and I will always go ahead of what you started with.

I will add a hint soon that will shift your thinking in the right direction...

Hint 1

> Adding the no-computers tag would make this even trickier.

Comment: Lines 3-5 looks like rot13(cubar, vcubar, vcubark) to me, but I can't fit that in with the rest. I think it's because I want that vcubark.

Comment: initial word possibly "exited"

Comment: Great guess, but this is a little more literal. :) @ALinuxLover

Comment: exited + c = excited was my thought process :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this refers to

> The symbols on the top row of a keyboard.

Start with me and I come last,

> This is the end bracket, ), found on the 0 key.

Add one and I become excited,

> This is the exclamation !, found on the 0+1 = 1 key.

Add another and I call someone,

> On PSE this is a tag call, @, on the 2 key.

Keep going and you will get something trendy,

> That's #socool #trendy #fam, #3key

Add another and you will want me,

> Everybody wants that $4k(ey)

Well now, add another and I will look like a weird balance,

> The % looks like a weird balance, on the 5 key

Add another and I'll bring you up,

> ^ is commonly used as exponentiation, on the 6 key

Yes, yes keep going and, and, and...?

> Yes, yes keep going &, &, & the 7 key

Well okay add another, and there will always be more.

> This could be because * represents multiplication and a wildcard, on the 8 key. Per @QuantumTwinkie, this represents that if you see * in text, there is always fine print or a footnote. (Condition applied!)

Add the last and final, and I will always go ahead of what you started with.

> This is the opening bracket, (, on the 9 key

Comment: Correct! Sbe gur "*" vg zrnag sbe vg gb or yvxr gur svar cevag. Bgurejvfr 100% pbeerpg! (ybir gur unfugntf!) :Q

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie #thanksfam! Haha that was a good puzzle!

Comment: drats, when i started typing it was unanswered!  hehe, good job

Comment: man, you are really good at this, great answer.

Comment: How did you...?

Answer (score 4):

you are

> the top line of the Qwerty keyboard, more specifically, the Shifted numbers from 0-9

Start with me and I come last,

> 0 is )

Add one and I become excited,

> 1 is !  (excitment)

Add another and I call someone,

> 2 is @ (to email someone)

Keep going and you will get something trendy,

> 3 is #  (trendy hashtag)

Add another and you will want me,

> 4 is $  (I want money!)

Well now, add another and I will look like a weird balance,

> 5 is %  (weird indeed)

Add another and I'll bring you up,

> 6 is ^ (going up?)

Yes, yes keep going and, and, and...?

> 7 is &  (and and and)

Well okay add another, and there will always be more.

> 8 is *  (wildcard)

Add the last and final, and I will always go ahead of what you started with.

> 9 is (  (which is always in front of ) )

Comment: This *is* the correct answer, however @El-Guest got it first.

Comment: yes, i saw :( should i delete mine?

Comment: I'm not sure what the rest of the community would say, but I would say nahhh keep the up vote :)

Comment: And have a second upvote from me too! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

This is as far as I got:

> .
>  I.
>  Hi.
>  Hip.
>  Chip

Comment: It's generally preferred to show which part of the solution matches which clue.

Comment: Not quite, I will add a hint soon to push people in the right direction. :)